# Mips: how to get the second character in a string

Tags: string, character, mips

How would one go about getting the second character of a string?
I've tried this but it doesn't seem to be working. `$t1` stores the string value.

```
lw $t2, 4($t1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
lb $t0, yourString
lb $a0, 1($t0)
li $v0, 11
syscall
```

So, entering hello would output e. You can increment the 1 to get the first, third, etc. characters.